# Performance of "in" condition query in db2

Tags: sql, db2, conditional-statements

I want to get the below data from a table in DB2 database.

```
select col1, col2, col3 from employee where employee_id in (1,2,3)
```

please share your thoughts on the performance of the query? Any alternatives?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? I've never used db2 but one obvious alternative is a range seek `where employee_id >= 1 and employee_id <= 3`

Comment: if there's a proper index on employee_id, absolutely no problem

Comment: And so long as the values part of the `in` clause isn't an un-correlated subselect.  DB2 on the iSeries has some performance implications in that case (range selection or an actual `join` tends to perform better)

Comment: @Martin Smith - would there be any performance difference between what you commented and an in?

Comment: @afuzzyllama - Don't know about db2 but in SQL Server there would be a minor benefit to the second one. The `IN` would be 3 index seeks meaning that the index is navigated from root to leaf 3 times. The `BETWEEN` would be a single index navigation. This is covered well here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx. For all I know db2 might do something completely different though.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I work with DB2 on the iSeries and it is a different beast... let me tell ya

Answer (score 2):

DB2's optimization of the IN predicate has traditionally been prone to estimating the cardinality of the result set wrong. With IN predicate it might have sometimes optimized for more results than what would made common sense.

Also it works exactly as Martin Smith above wrote - running 3 separate indexed queries in order. That is repairable by either enabling the optimization

```
db2set DB2_INLIST_TO_NLJN=true
```

which forces DB2 to create a temporary virtual table and perform nested loop join (in many cases a very well performing option) **or** by switching to a different kind of query such as the ranged version. You can also nudge the DB2 to use a nested loop join version like

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from employee, (values 1,2,3) as v(ids) 
where employee_id=v.ids
```

Please keep in mind that this is all somewhat academical unless you have a significant amount of items in your IN query and rows in the target table, and have to run great amounts of such queries.